# Is it possible to allow distinct but for 2 values only?

Tags: db2

i have a problem that i cannot solve or think about anything that could help me.
Example output below.
In Column4 there are 3 type of value  3 piece of Random number1 and 3 piece of Random number2...etc.
My goal is to show only 2 type of that value in column4. In this example the rows with "*" mark.
So this way i get 6 rows of data.
But the values of the column4 are completely random.
Maybe i get 10000 row and from that only 700 is unique the rest is repetition of that 700 in column4.
I may have oversimplified this slection but thats for me to easily understand this whole thing.

```
I have this:
UN_ID_DATE             UN_ID      OBJ             Task                                Random_ID     
-------------------    -------    --------------  -------------------------------     -------  
2021-02-24 10:33:24    157        Elol            Einschlcsse                         9999999    
2021-02-24 10:24:59    191        Biva            Polierstelle                        4444444  
2021-02-24 10:23:38    185        oldal           Karobau Schleifstelle               4444444  
2021-02-24 10:23:26    173        Tuf             Delle                               2222222  
2021-02-24 10:20:06    173        Tuf             Delle                               3333333  
2021-02-24 10:18:22    191        Biva            Polierstelle                        9999999  
2021-02-24 10:16:29    185        oldal           Kratzer                             9999999 


Goal:
UN_ID_DATE             UN_ID      OBJ             Task                                Random_ID     
-------------------    -------    --------------  -------------------------------     -------  
2021-02-24 10:33:24    157        Elol            Einschlcsse                         9999999  
2021-02-24 10:18:22    191        Biva            Polierstelle                        9999999  
2021-02-24 10:16:29    185        oldal           Kratzer                             9999999
2021-02-24 10:24:59    191        Biva            Polierstelle                        4444444  
2021-02-24 10:23:38    185        oldal           Karobau Schleifstelle               4444444
```

In the desired dataset there are all the Random_ID which is similar to the first 2 that differ. So 999999 and 4444444 are different so i need all the rows with Random_ID 9999999 and 4444444 which is 5 rows. This was ordered by DATE and this Date belongs to UN_ID.

Thank you in advance Guys! :)

Comment: You must describe a rule for these Rundom numbers selection. E.g. why rnd1 and rnd3 are chosen and not, say, rnd1 and rnd2 or rnd2 and rnd3.

Comment: For those random numbers belong a date, and arranged accordingly, and with that ordering there will be those numbers on the column4 and i need the first 2 which differs, aaand i need all of the rows with those 2 in column4 which can be up to 20 or 100.

Comment: Quite a vague description... Did I get you right, that: `column4` has `date` data type, and you need all the rows having 1-st 2 earliest date values in this column?

Comment: Im really sorry about that. Im not native english so its hard to explain for me, but ill try again. Column4 have a random number like 2345671 and  for this number belong a UniquethingX value (which is a text or a number) this Uniquething is a Status and the Random number has multiple Statuses and for this Status belong a  date column which is hidden because it isnt needed to be visible. (One type of random number has multiple statuses, these Statuses have dates and the whole table is ordered by date and thats why i get multiple and similar Random numbers.

Comment: And i need the first 2 of those random numbers but with all the Statuses which are in separate rows so this way i get for example 34 rows of data with all the statuses but for 2 Random numbers. I see ive explaind it very wrong. I hope this is more clear. Sorry :)

Comment: Now it's absolutely unclear... Please, edit your question with a sample dataset with real values, the result set desired, and clear explanation of why namely these particular rows  in the result set are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a handy OLAP function `DENSE_RANK` you may use for that.
Try this, uncommenting the commented out line:

```
WITH MYTAB (RANDOM_ID) AS
(
VALUES
  9999999
, 4444444
, 4444444
, 2222222
, 3333333
, 9999999
, 9999999 
)
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT T.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY RANDOM_ID DESC) RN_ 
FROM MYTAB T
)
--WHERE RN_ <= 2
;
```

There result is:

```
|RANDOM_ID|RN_|
|---------|---|
|9999999  |1  |
|9999999  |1  |
|9999999  |1  |
|4444444  |2  |
|4444444  |2  |
|3333333  |3  |
|2222222  |4  |
```